# Pseudoprime $n$ to the base $b$ relation to $\prod\limits_{p\mid n}\gcd(p−1, n−1)$

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm, pseudoprimes

> Let $n > 1$ be an odd number, and let $P_n = \{b\pmod{n} : b^{n−1}\equiv 1\pmod{n}\}$ be the set of bases $b$ for which $n$ is a pseudoprime to the
>    base $b$. Prove that  $|P_n| = \prod\limits_{p\mid n}\gcd(p−1, n−1)$.

I have found that $|P_n| = \left(\gcd (p-1, n-1)\right)^2$

But how can I conclude that what I found is equivalent to $\prod\limits_{p\mid n}\gcd(p−1, n−1)$. In other words, how does $\left(\gcd (p-1, n-1)\right)^2 = \prod\limits_{p\mid n}\gcd(p−1, n−1)$ ?

NOTE: How I found that $|P_n| = \left(\gcd (p-1, n-1)\right)^2$ is very similar to the answer to this question: [Prove that $n$ is a pseudoprime to the base $b$ if and only if $b^d\equiv1 \pmod n$...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523326/prove-that-n-is-a-pseudoprime-to-the-base-b-if-and-only-if-bd-equiv1-pmod?rq=1)

Comment: thank you for the edit! and instead of "the sum of gcd..." .. i meant "the product of the gcd...". i'm just not too sure how to insert such symbol. @PeterWoolfitt

Comment: I changed the sums to products - is it better now, or is something still not right? By the way, here is a guide for how to format mathematics on this site http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: thats perfect! thanks :) @PeterWoolfitt

Comment: Happy to be of help!